# Angular $http service - force not parsing response to JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, parsing, http, httpresponse

I have a "test.ini" file in my server, contain the following text:

```
"[ALL_OFF]
 [ALL_ON]
"
```

I'm trying to get this file content via `$http` service, here is part of my function:

```
  var params = { url: 'test.ini'};
 $http(params).then(
                 function (APIResponse)
                   {
                     deferred.resolve(APIResponse.data);
                   },
                    function (APIResponse)
                   {
                     deferred.reject(APIResponse);
                   });
```

This operation got an Angular exception (SyntaxError: Unexpected token A).
I opened the Angular framework file, and I found the exeption:
Because the text file content start with "**[**" and end with "**]**", Angular "think" that is a JSON file.

Here is the Angular code (line 7474 in **1.2.23 version**):

```
 var defaults = this.defaults = {
    // transform incoming response data
    transformResponse: [function(data) {
      if (isString(data)) {
        // strip json vulnerability protection prefix
        data = data.replace(PROTECTION_PREFIX, '');
        if (JSON_START.test(data) && JSON_END.test(data))
          data = fromJson(data);
      }
      return data;
    }],
```

My question:

How can I **force** angular to **not** make this check (`if (JSON_START.test(data) && JSON_END.test(data))`) and **not** parse the text response to JSON?

Comment: Make your server to return file with `text/plain` then it will work just fine

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can override the defaults by this:

```
$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: [function (data) {
      // Do whatever you want!
      return data;
  }]
});
```

The function above replaces the default function you have posted for this HTTP request.

Or read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) where they wrote "Overriding the Default Transformations Per Request".

Comment: Or simply `transformResponse: undefined` for no transformation.

Comment: @dfsq this the answer I looked for - "transformResponse: undefined", thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can also force angular to treat the response as plain text and not JSON:

```
$http({
    url: '...',
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'text'
});
```

This will make sure that Angular doesn't try to auto detect the content type.

Comment: It doesn't work because `content-type` in response header is wrong (probably `application/json`). Infact if server provides correct `content-type` you don't need to add `responseType: 'text'` in your configuration, and angular will respect that.

Comment: @AlirezaMirian that's true. The only reason to add it in Angular is so it doesn't try to parse it as JSON if no `content-type` is provided by the server.