# get value of http.get angular js when response is text

Tags: angularjs, http

I have a angular js controller with a http get. I need get response value of http. In headers I send:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YGDJSDJH4564363YTESNSBS4="
```

The response is a simple text: eg. 'va'

my code:

```js
$http({
            
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'some_url',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic '+tenant_auth }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.page_error = response;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.page_error = '';
            }, 10000);
        });
```

The request return ok, but the error is when I try to print the response.

```
angular.min.js:117 SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at uc (https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:17:36)
at ac (https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:91:229)
at https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:92:143
at q (https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:7:355)
at fd (https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:92:125)
at c (https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:93:373)
at https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:130:226
at n.$eval (https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:144:467)
at n.$digest (https://mltest.sorbasoft.net/machinelearner/js/angular.min.js:142:47)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the content type is `application/json` angular will try to parse it. Try sending `text/plain` instead.

Comment: I tryed, pass 'content-type': 'text/plain' in headers. but the api return the same error

Comment: The answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765309/angular-http-service-force-not-parsing-response-to-json

Answer (score -1):

In addition to other answers, You always able to use `$.ajax` or jQuery

In angular the default is `JSON`. in jQuery the default is `text`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'some_url',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic '+tenant_auth }
  }).then(function successCallback(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.$apply() // Do not forgot to do this every time you change scope outside of angular functions
  }, function errorCallback(data) {
            $scope.page_error = data;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.page_error = '';
                $scope.$apply() // Do not forgot to do this when you use jQuery ajax.
            }, 10000);
            $scope.$apply()
        });
```